# I am tyring to download Multiple images as a zip file in javascript

Tags: javascript, laravel

I am trying to download multiple images when i click to download button but unfortunately i am getting empty folder in zip file , images or files are not downloading in zip file please help me how can i resolve that ? thanks.

[image: empty folder download]

[image: inbox table]

**HTML View**

```
@if($digitizingInbox->file )
  <button class="download btn btn-warning">Download</button>
@endif
```

**Script**

```
<script src="{{ url('') }}/js/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script src="{{ url('') }}/js/saveas.js"></script>

<script>
  window.onload = function(event) {

    let val = document.querySelector('.download')

    let url = "{{config('yourstitchart.file_url')}}"
    // let url http://localhost/yourstitchart.com/web/public/uploads/images/
    alert(url);

    let files = {!!$digitizingInbox->file!!}
    // let files = favicon-new.png,phpG70dmT.png
    alert(files);

    var zip = new JSZip();
    //skip this step if you don't want your files in a folder.

    var folder = zip.folder("files");

    files.map(async item => folder.file(url + item))

    //...so on until you have completed adding files

    val.addEventListener("click", (e) => {

      zip.generateAsync({
          type: "blob"
        })

        .then(function(content) {

          //see FileSaver.js
          saveAs(content, "example.zip");
        });
    });
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

I didn't have your entire project so I wasn't exactly sure what's going on here.. But I thought it was interesting and I found a js-fiddle that was pretty close to what it seems you were doing here and adapted it a bit. Unless this is an assignment that requires a very specific approach I think this will work for you:

[codepen to download image files as a zip file](https://jsfiddle.net/bgoonz/1dye9uws/)

The dependencies are as follows:

[jquery](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js)
[Jzip](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.5/jszip.min.js)
[Jzip Utils](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip-utils/0.0.2/jszip-utils.min.js)
[File Saver](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/FileSaver.js/1.3.8/FileSaver.min.js)

```js
let links = [];

$('.gallery').on('click', '.thumb', function () {

  $(this).removeClass().addClass('thumbChecked');
  $(this).css("border", "2px solid #c32032");
  links.push($(this).attr('src'));
  console.log(links);
  
  if (links.length != 0) {
    $('.download').css("display", "block");
  }

});


$('.gallery').on('click', '.thumbChecked', function () {

  $(this).removeClass().addClass('thumb');
  $(this).css("border", "2px solid white");
  let itemtoRemove = $(this).attr('src');
  links.splice($.inArray(itemtoRemove, links), 1);
  console.log(links);
  
  if (links.length == 0) {
    $('.download').css("display", "none");
  }

});


function generateZIP() {
  console.log('TEST');
  let zip = new JSZip();
  let count = 0;
  let zipFilename = "Pictures.zip";

  links.forEach(function (url, i) {
    let filename = links[i];
    filename = filename.replace(/[\/\*\|\:\<\>\?\"\\]/gi, '').replace("httpsi.imgur.com","");
    // loading a file and add it in a zip file
    JSZipUtils.getBinaryContent(url, function (err, data) {
      if (err) {
        throw err; // or handle the error
      }
      zip.file(filename, data, { binary: true });
      count++;
      if (count == links.length) {
        zip.generateAsync({ type: 'blob' }).then(function (content) {
          saveAs(content, zipFilename);
        });
      }
    });
  });
}
```

```html
  
  
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
   <style>    </style>
    <script async defer src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script async defer src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip-utils/0.0.2/jszip-utils.min.js"></script>
    <script async defer src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.5/jszip.min.js"></script>
    <script async defer src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/FileSaver.js/1.3.8/FileSaver.min.js"></script>
<style>

    .gallery {
        text-align: center;
    }
    .gallery>img {
        width: 100px;
        opacity: .8;
    }
    .gallery>img:hover {
        cursor: pointer;
        opacity: 1;
    }
    .imgContainer {
        padding-top: 10px;
    }

    .thumb {
        height: 110px;
        width: 160px;
        margin: 10px;
        padding: 2px;
        box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px rgba(70, 70, 70, 0.6);
        border: 2px solid white;
    }

    .thumb:hover {
        box-shadow: 3px 3px 6px rgba(70, 70, 70, 0.8);
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .thumbChecked {
        opacity: .8;
        height: 110px;
        width: 160px;
        margin: 10px;
        padding: 2px;
        box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px rgba(70, 70, 70, 0.6);
    }
    .download {
        margin-top: 20px;
        display: none;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }


</style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="gallery">

      <div class="imgContainer">
        <img class="thumb"
          src="https://i.imgur.com/emBm6jv.jpg">
        <img class="thumb" src="https://i.imgur.com/l49aYS3.jpg">
        <img class="thumb" src="https://i.imgur.com/a0bs8oJ.jpg">
        <img class="thumb" src="https://i.imgur.com/PHYkTp9.jpg">
        <img class="thumb" src="https://i.imgur.com/a7fJPfn.jpg">
        <img class="thumb" src="https://i.imgur.com/WCzfMMt.jpg">
        <img class="thumb" src="https://i.imgur.com/QCFXhpg.jpg">
        <img class="thumb" src="https://i.imgur.com/esOG86I.jpg">
        <img class="thumb" src="https://i.imgur.com/LW8EKdK.jpg">
        <img class="thumb" src="https://i.imgur.com/ggECswm.jpg">
        <img class="thumb" src="https://i.imgur.com/CHKrDLa.jpg">
        <video src="https://i.imgur.com/JpljA8l.mp4" autoplay="" loop="" class="thumb"
          style="max-width: 100%; height: 110px;">
          <source type="video/mp4" src="https://i.imgur.com/JpljA8l.mp4">
        </video>
      </div>

      <img class="download" src="https://maxcdn.icons8.com/app/uploads/2016/10/download1.png" onclick="generateZIP()" />

    </div>
  

</body>
</html>
```